# Bochner Integral for Frechet spaces

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

We have a definition of the Bochner integral https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bochner_integral. Is it possible to define the same construction for Frechet space valued functions? 
My space (over which I want to integrate) is very good, say $\mathbb{C}^l.$

Comment: take a look [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/47721/weak-and-strong-integration-of-vector-valued-functions), it could help